# Hive Utf-8 Encoding number of characters supported?

Tags: hadoop, utf-8, hive

Hi actually the problem is as follows the data i want to insert in hive table has latin words and its in utf-8 encoded format. But still hive does not display it properly.

Actual Data:-
[image: Actual Data]

Data Inserted in hive

[image: Hive Data]

I changed the encoding of the table to utf-8 as well still same issue below are the hive DDL and commands

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test6
(
CONTACT_RECORD_ID    string,
ACCOUNT    string,
CUST    string,
NUMBER    string,
NUMBER1    string,
NUMBER2    string,
NUMBER3    string,
NUMBER4    string,
NUMBER5    string,
NUMBER6    string,
NUMBER7    string,
LIST    string
)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|';
ALTER TABLE test6 SET serdeproperties ('serialization.encoding'='UTF-8');
```

Does hive support only the first 128 characters of UTF-8?
Please do suggest.

Comment: _"hive does not display it properly"_ -- did you make sure it's not a *display* artifact, indeed? Did you enforce `export LANG=en_US.UTF-8` and checked that your terminal app expects UTF-8 (e.g. with PuTTY, _Window > Translation > Remote charset = UTF-8_)?

Comment: Also, did you download one of the HDFS files and run `file` command on it, just to make sure it actually detects UTF-8 content?

Comment: Did you find any solution @cheta Pulate? If yes please mention here Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

this may not be ideal solution , but this works. Hive somehow doesn't seem to treat them as UTF8. Please try to create the table with following parameters:

```
CREATE TABLE testjoins.yt_sample_mapping_1(
   `col1` string,
   `col2` string,
   `col3` string)
   ROW FORMAT SERDE "org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe"
   WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ( "separatorChar" = ",", 
    "quoteChar" = "\"", 
    "escapeChar" = "\\", 
    "serialization.encoding"='ISO-8859-1') 
    TBLPROPERTIES ( 'store.charset'='ISO-8859-1', 
    'retrieve.charset'='ISO-8859-1');
```

Answer (score 2):

For me adding following line worked.

```
TBLPROPERTIES('serialization.encoding'='windows-1252')
```

Example code:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test.tbl
(
    name string,
    gender string,
    age string,
    address string
)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' STORED AS TEXTFILE
LOCATION 'adl://<Data-Lake-Store>.azuredatalakestore.net/<Folder-Name>/'
TBLPROPERTIES('serialization.encoding'='windows-1252');
```

Comment: Dis this above DDL work for you as per your TBLPROPERTIES('serialization.encoding'='windows-1252');

Comment: Did  this above DDL work for you as per your TBLPROPERTIES('serialization.encoding'='windows-1252');

Comment: Did  this above DDL work for you as per your TBLPROPERTIES('serialization.encoding'='windows-1252');